# How to put a title for check box column in Bootstrap Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table and have a column of check box type.

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
        field: 'GroupId',
        title: 'Group ID'
    }, {
        field: 'IsActive',
        title: 'Active',
        checkbox: true
    }]
});
```

When i am using 'checkbox:true' then the column comes with checkbox icon including the header. Can i keep the check box icons in rows but a title for header ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add two configurations:

- First **disable** default **checkbox header** in **table options** adding:

`checkboxHeader: false`

- **Enable checkbox title** & setup custom title in **column options** adding:

```
checkbox: true,
showSelectTitle: true,
field: 'IsActive',
title: 'Active'
```

- In your example:

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    checkboxHeader: false,
    columns: [{
        field: 'GroupId',
        title: 'Group ID'
    }, {
        checkbox: true,
        showSelectTitle: true,
        field: 'IsActive',
        title: 'Active'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="testbedsTable"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-search="true"
               data-checkbox-header="false">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" data-field="State" data-checkbox="true" id="tableDefaultCheck" data-show-select-title="true">Validate</th>
```

whereas **data-checkbox-header="false"** and **data-show-select-title="true">Validate** solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran a sample of this and I was able to get it to work when adapting it to a sample I already have. I doubt it is populating the checkbox properly but I wasn't concerned with trying to make that work.
http://www.codeply.com/go/h7PZLLTY0b

```
{
            field: 'price',
            title: 'Item Price',
            checkbox: true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    field: 'ActionField',
    title: '',
    sortable: false,
    width: '25',
    halign: "center",
    formatter: "CheckBoxFormat",
    checkbox: false,
    clickToSelect: true,
},


function CheckBoxFormat(value, row) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" class="chk" data-ID="' + row.ID + '" onclick="AddRemoveItems(this);"/>';
}
```

Comment: this means the user will lose all checkbox capabilities provided by the api.